# Obtain username in a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

I am trying to obtain the logged user name in a form, but I am having the following error message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

What am I doing wrong?

I guess there is something wrong with

```
self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
self.user_name =self.request.user.username
```

Here is my form

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

List = forms.ChoiceField(choices=())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    self.user_name =self.request.user.username  
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['List'].choices = self.list_people()

def list_people(self):      
    u = User.objects.get(username=self.user_name).accesslevel.segmentation.split(',')
    v=(('---------','---------'),)
    for l in u:
        v=v+((l.lstrip(),l.lstrip()),)
    return v
```

Views.py

```
def list_table(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST,request=request)
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    ....
```

Traceback

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\folder..\views.py", line 74, in list_table
    form = MyForm()
  File "C:\Users\PC\folder..\forms.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.user = self.request.user.username
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: Are you sure you pass in the request when initialising for the form in the other branch, for GET?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am sorry, but I didn't understand your question. Can you explain me a little bit more?

Comment: Do you have any other solution? Because I am really stuck on it? I just need to pass info from view to use in the form

Comment: When request is not POST, you presumably do `form = ApartmentForm()`. You need to pass in the request there too. If that's not the solution, you should post the full traceback.

Comment: Updated with the traceback and the views

Comment: So, the problem is *exactly as I said*. In the else branch, you are not passing the request. Why is that not clear?

Comment: I am new in Django.. Can you please answer with the code that I should include?

Comment: Now I got... You were correct.. I found the error in a complete different else statement.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the request also when the method is GET, not only when is POST.

```
def list_table(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request=request)
    else:
        form = MyForm(request=request)
```

Anyway, if you only want the user, you already have access to that in the view, doing `request.user`